# Is return after for loop same as continue in python?

Tags: python

I know this might be a duplicate but I couldn't find it by searching. I was wondering if the following case is true:

```
def foo(A):
    for i in range(10):
        if A[i] < 10:
            return
        A[i] = A[i] - 10
```

what happens when the above `return`? I know it doesn't end the function because it after the **for loop**. Is it same as having `continue`?

Comment: "I know it doesn't end the function" - Yes it does end the function. I suggest you read up on [functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: No, `continue` just goes to the next iteration. `return` will **always** end the function. It doesn't matter where you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you are within a function, `return` will exit it. The only exception to this is for nested functions (a `def` inside a `def`).

So what will happen is that when `A[i] < 10` is `True`, it will exit.

Answer (score 0):

No, `return` jumps out of the function `foo()`. If you replace it by a `continue` the execution will continue with the next value for `i` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

No matter if its inside or outside of any loop type, `return` has the same functionality, ending and returning a value (if given) of the surrounding function. If there is a `return` statement within a loop, assuming the condition for it to be executed is true, the entire function will be ended.

With a `continue` statement, if the condition for its execution is true, the remainder of the iteration code is skipped and it moves to the next iteration of the loop, not exiting or ending the function.

And just in case you need this information too, the `break` statement is the intermediate between the functionality of the `continue` and `return` statements. If executed within any loop, it will end the entire **loop** and move on with the remainder of the code for the given function/operation.